# Can base saturation percentage be greater than 100%?

Tags: biogeochemistry, soil-science

I have been doing some quality analysis on soil analytical data that I've gathered from some environmental impact assessments.  Many of the values for base saturation percentage are well over 100% (some over 500%).  Since I am not a soil scientist, I was hoping that someone could confirm for me whether or not it is possible for base saturation percentage to be greater than 100%?

It's my understanding that base saturation percentage is [the proportion of the cation exchange capacity (CEC) made up by the base cations (sodium, magnesium, potassium and calcium)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cation-exchange_capacity#Base_saturation).  As [base saturation is a fraction of the total CEC](https://www.clemson.edu/public/regulatory/ag-srvc-lab/soil-testing/cec-calculations.html#:%7E:text=To%20calculate%20the%20percent%20base,Multiply%20the%20result%20by%20100%25.), I don't see how it would be possible for the base saturation percentage to ever be greater than 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation is probably caused by free Ca ions in the soil solution.
I've found an article that talks about high PBS.
Take a look at this reference, hope it helps
Tomašic, M., Zgorelec, Ž., Jurišic, A., & Kisic, I. (2013). Cation exchange capacity of dominant soil types in the Republic of Croatia. Journal of Central European Agriculture.

Comment: That seems to clear it up!  Quoting your reference, [Tomašic et al. say](https://jcea.agr.hr/articles/774521_CATION_EXCHANGE_CAPACITY_OF_DOMINANT_SOIL_TYPES_IN_THE_REPUBLIC_OF_CROATIA__en.pdf): _Base saturation
higher than 100% indicates the presence of soluble salts or lime, and free cations
which are not attached to the soil complex._